# MyBatis google Guava support

Tags: java, orm, guava, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I want to use google  Guava collections as return types (resultType/resultMap) in MyBatis, and I wanted to know if this is supported out of the box. I did not find any official documentation regarding the same.

1. Are Guava collections supported as return types out of the box ? If so, how can these be enabled? I am specifically looking to use Guava MultiMap and Table.
2. If it is not supported out of the box, how can I make this work? How can I manually cast the resultset to the collection/data structure I want?

I am using Java 8, MyBatis 3.4.1 and MySQL as a DB

Thanks in advance!